# Emacs multiple hl-line faces/change line hook?

Tags: emacs

I was updating my emacs (I use doom btw) config when I came across a problem. I want to flash the current line for all movement operations. I also want a constant effect on the current line. I'm able to do one or the other, but thus far I can't find a way to do both.

Currently, I have a box around the line that I want to always be present. I would like the background to flash on any movement, (e.g. line changes, frame focusing). I can use hl-line+.el to flash the line when it moves, but this seems to co-opt the hl-line face. It forces me to choose between constant line highlight and line highlighting on movement. I also can use nav-flash to flash on changing buffers, but this does not react to line changes. Is there a hook I can add nav-flash to? Is there a way I can override hl-line+ to use a different face and allow the line to be highlighted normally too? For what it's worth, here are my current config settings:

```
((hl-line &override)
 :background bg
 :box '(
         :color "#fb7d32"
         :line-width -1))
(nav-flash-face
 :foreground bg
 :background "#fb7d32")
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated, I would consider myself an intermediate emacs user, so I'm not afraid to write my own functions and hooks if thats what this comes to. Regardless, thank you in advance for your help and suggestions!

I'm on emacs 26.3 with doom installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hl-line-flash`, from [`hl-line+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-line%2b.el) just uses `hl-line-highlight`.

And that function just reuses the existing overlay.  That overlay (created by `hl-line-make-overlay`) uses the value of variable `hl-line-face`.

What you could do is advise `hl-line-flash` with an `:around` advice, so that it does this:

1. Binds `hl-line-face` to the face you want to flash with.
2. Deletes the existing overlay (`hl-line-overlay`).
3. Then invokes the original definition of `hl-line-highlight-now`.

There are no doubt other ways to do what you want, as well.  One way is to just define your own command to use in place of `hl-line-flash`, with code that does the same thing as the above advice description.  Just do that around the call to `hl-line-highlight-now`, so that function uses the face you want for flashing.